# How do I write this JPA query that requires a JOIN?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, join, jpa-2.0

I'm using JPA 2.0, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user",
    uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "USER_NAME" }) }
)
public class User implements Comparable<User>, Serializable
{
    ...
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotNull
    /* the first name of the User */
    private String firstName;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="code_user",
    uniqueConstraints = { 
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "SAMPLE_WORD_ID", "USER_ID" }) }
)
public class CodeUser 
{

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-strategy")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private Code code;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = true)
    private User user;
```

How do I write a JPA/CriteriaBuilder query to find all User objects who's first name matches "Dave" and who are tied to a Code record in which the code is "abode"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have missed an HQL syntax element

```
SELECT user FROM CodeUser codeUser 
    JOIN FETCH codeUser.user user
    JOIN FETCH codeUser.code code 
        WHERE user.firstName = 'Dave' AND code.value = 'abode'
```

assuming `Code` has a field `value` holding the value `"abode"`. You might not need the `FETCH`.

You can always replace the literal values with a placeholder like `?` or a named placeholder like `:name` and set their values from the `Query` object.